conditional split based on list of column
I have a dataframe having 2 column - "id" (int) and "values" (list of struct). I need to split on name. I have a list of column names as delimiter. I need to check the occurence of column names from the list, if one of the column name is present , then split the dataframe.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType

value_schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([
        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("location", StringType(), True)
    ])
)

data = [
    (1, [
        {"name": "col1_US", "location": "usa"},
        {"name": "col2_name_plex", "location": "usa"},
        {"name": "col4_false", "location": "usa"},
        {"name": "col3_name_is_fantasy", "location": "usa"}
    ])
]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "values"])

df = df.withColumn("values", explode(col("values")).alias("values"))
df = df.select(col("id"),col("values.name").alias("name"))
df.display()


col_names = ["col1","col2_name","col3_name_is","col4"]

for c in col_names:
    #if (df["name"].contains(c)):  # this is not working
    split_data = split(df["name"], f'{c}_')
    df = df.withColumns({
        "new_name": lit(c),
        "new_value": split_data.getItem(1)
        })
df.display()

Data after cleanup:
id  name
1   col1_US
1   col2_name_plex
1   col4_false_val
1   col3_name_is_fantasy

Final data from above script:
# returning unexpected data

id    name                new_name  new_value
1   col1_US               col4      null
1   col2_name_plex        col4      null
1   col4_false_val        col4      false
1   col3_name_is_fantasy  col4      null

Expected Result:
id    name                new_name          new_value
1   col1_US               col1              US
1   col2_name_plex        col2_name         plex
1   col4_false_val        col4              false_val
1   col3_name_is_fantasy  col3_name_is      fantasy


We can use a regular expression to create field new_name from your list of desired col_names:
col_names = ["col1","col2_name","col3_name_is","col4"]
pattern = "|".join(col_names)

df = df.withColumn("new_name", regexp_extract("name", pattern, 0))

+---+--------------------+------------+
| id|                name|    new_name|
+---+--------------------+------------+
|  1|             col1_US|        col1|
|  1|      col2_name_plex|   col2_name|
|  1|          col4_false|        col4|
|  1|col3_name_is_fantasy|col3_name_is|
+---+--------------------+------------+

Then we can split using another regular expression where we pass new_name as the pattern we want to match, and only get alphanumeric symbols after that (so that we don't pull in "_").
df.withColumn(
    "new_value", 
    expr("regexp_replace(split(name, new_name)[1], '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '')")
)

+---+--------------------+------------+---------+
| id|                name|    new_name|new_value|
+---+--------------------+------------+---------+
|  1|             col1_US|        col1|       US|
|  1|      col2_name_plex|   col2_name|     plex|
|  1|          col4_false|        col4|    false|
|  1|col3_name_is_fantasy|col3_name_is|  fantasy|
+---+--------------------+------------+---------+


thank you. this works for most cases.I missed one instance, where value part can have multiple spaces. for instance 'col3_name_is_fantasy_val', here new_name is 'col3_name_is' and new_value is 'fantasy_val'. Above code handles new_name, but new_value is coming as 'fantasyval'. How to handle such cases, I tried to something like  split(df['name'], concat(df['new_name'],lit('_')))[1]  but getting an error Column is not iterable.

also tried below code, running into same error df = df.withColumn(     "new_value",      split(df['name'], concat(df['new_name'], lit('_')))[1] )

posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78671358/split-a-datafarme-column-based-on-another-column-column-is-not-iterable
